# Would ES7 behave like the function was fully synchronous here?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, ecmascript-2016

The following case:
I have a wrapperfunction "InitializePage()" which is called when loading the page.
This one contains the functions a-d out of which a and b contain AJAX. It would look like this:

```js
function wrapperFunction() {

  a() //contains AJAX
  b() //contains AJAX
  c() //Synchronous
  d() //Synchronous

}
```

Now, I want function b to start only if function a has finished already. 
I know that I could easily do this by making the wrapperFunction "async", use "await" in front of function a and then return the promise from function a (using JQuery Ajax) like this:

```js
function a() {
  return $.post('somefile.php', {
    //someCode
  })
}
```

But I want to know one thing:
function a by itself should be treated by JS as SYNCHRONOUS code until it hits the JqueryAJAX inside the function, right? 
Only when it hits the AJAX call, JS hands it off to the C++ API and continues to the next bit of code no matter whether the AJAX call has finished execution yet or not, right?

So lets assume, even though it would be unnecessarily hacky, I would do this:

```js
async function a() {

  await $.post('someFile.php', {
    //some code
  })
}
```

Since I synchronized the AJAX part of function a(), would this mean that at the level of wrapperFunction(), JS does NOT procede until function a() and all of its contents have finished execution?

Comment: It might help to look at the `await` code and think of what it would look like when it was written with `.then()`

Comment: You need to write `await a()` in `wrapperFunction()` to make it seem like it's synchronous. And then you need to declare `async function wrapperFunction()`

Comment: @Barmar I know this way, but out of curiosity, I wanted to know whether the way I described would work as well or not.

Comment: The simple answer is no. Declaring a function `async` is just syntactic sugar for automatically returning a promise. It doesn't make it act synchronous. The `await` keyword is what makes a call to an async function seem like it's synchronous.

Comment: but the keyword "async" doesn't make a function return promises? Instead, an async function enables the await keyword for use INSIDE the async function, which can await promises being returned from any function inside the function which was prefixed with "async" .

Comment: the answer is yes for your question.

Comment: @Barmar If  `async` was only syntactic sugar then the use of `await` wouldn't be possible ^^

Comment: @abetteroliver `await` is also syntactic sugar. The two of them work together to hide the promises and callbacks, but they still exist.

Comment: @Barmar `async` makes a function resumable. That's hardly syntactic sugar. It's simply impossible with regular functions. The same is true for generator functions. That's why transpilers use them to emulate `async` / `await`.

Comment: @abetteroliver I knew about generators, didn't know that async could do that as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **async** function declaration defines an **asynchronous** function, which returns an **AsyncFunction** object. An asynchronous function is a function which operates asynchronously via the event loop, using an implicit **Promise** to return its result. But the syntax and structure of your code using async functions is much more like using standard synchronous functions.

So as per your question.

```
async function a() {

  await $.post('someFile.php', {
    //some code
  })
}
```

yes it makes it asynchronous. but it is always better to use await where we are calling this function something like below.

for more refrenece please take a look [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function).

```
function resolveAfter2Seconds() {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      resolve('resolved');
    }, 2000);
  });
}

async function asyncCall() {
  console.log('calling');
  var result = await resolveAfter2Seconds();
  console.log(result);
  // expected output: 'resolved'
}

asyncCall();
```

Comment: Thanks, yes it seems to work! :=)
And yeah I know the way you outlined is better, I usually do it that way as well. But this time I have to operate from an AJAX thenable where a series of further AJAX calls is made. Since I want to avoid a huge pyramide of thenables and at the same time cant use the "await" keyword inside a then(), I want to do it this way. Or can you show me how to use the await keyword inside a then? If so, I can open up another question for this, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

If we take "fully asynchronous" to mean that there is nothing put on the [Event Loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/EventLoop) then no, your function `a` would not become fully synchronous.

Using async/await does not make asynchronous code synchronous, it is simply syntax that helps the developer reason with Promises more easily, essentially by abstracting away the Promise API into the language.

> Since I synchronized the AJAX part of function a(), would this mean that at the level of wrapperFunction(), JS does NOT procede until function a() and all of its contents have finished execution?

With the caveat that your function `a` is *not* "synchronized" by using async/await, callers of `a` can still wait for its execution to complete before continuing to the next statement, but only if the call to `a` is made using the `await` keyword, like so:

```
async function a () {
  return someAsyncOperation()
}

async function waitsOnA () {
  console.log('a started')
  await a()
  console.log('a completed')
}

// equivalent to
function waitsOnA () {
  console.log('a started')
  a().then(() => {
    console.log('a completed')
  })
}
```